# com.apple.quarantine extended attribute gets re-added each time I open the file

Tags: macos, command-line

I have a file called tasks.taskpaper that I associated with [FoldingText](http://www.foldingtext.com). When I open the file, the dialog pops up with text

> “tasks.taskpaper” may be a script application. It was created by
>   FoldingText and will be opened by FoldingText. Are you sure you want
>   to open it?

And, indeed, the com.apple.quarantine extended attribute is associated with the file:

```
$ xattr -l tasks.taskpaper | grep com.apple.quarantine
com.apple.quarantine: 0002;53b0afc9;FoldingText;
```

I can remove the attribute:

```
$ xattr -d com.apple.quarantine tasks.taskpaper
$ xattr -l tasks.taskpaper | grep com.apple.quarantine
$
```

But when I open the file with FoldingText again, I get the popup dialog again, and the attribute has somehow been re-added to the file:

```
$ xattr -l tasks.taskpaper | grep com.apple.quarantine
com.apple.quarantine: 0002;53b0b0dc;FoldingText;
```

How can I get this to stop happening?

Note that I'm running on Mavericks and I installed FoldingText (2.0.2) using the App Store. Also, the file is in a Dropbox directory.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add *the direct path to the file*  in your command to remove it permanently:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /complete/path/to/tasks.taskpaper
```

If this fails, there may be multiple instances. Attempt to [globally remove](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87313/how-to-remove-xattr-com-apple-quarantine-from-all-webarchive-files-with-that-ex) it amongst all versions:

```
find . -iname '*.taskpaper' -print0 | xargs -0 xattr -d com.apple.quarantine
```